# Title for zend framework input elements

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Hi, I'm trying to add a title attribute to the input element created this way

```
$this->createElement('text', 'tv_id', array(
        'label'      => 'Tv Id',
        'class'      => 'htmlfivify_number',
        'readonly'      => 'True',
        'required'      => False,
        'filters'    => array('Int'),
        'validators'    => array('Digits', 'Int')
));
```

I tried adding a `'title' = "some title text'` in the options but it didn't show up,
I want to add this title attribute so that it shows up as a tooltip when the user mouse overs an input.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$element = $this->createElement('text', 'tv_id', array(
    'label'      => 'Tv Id',
    'class'      => 'htmlfivify_number',
    'readonly'      => 'True',
    'required'      => False,
    'filters'    => array('Int'),
    'validators'    => array('Digits', 'Int')
));
$element->setAttrib('title', 'My title text');
```

Should get you your title.

[From the ZF manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.metadata)

> Form elements may require additional metadata. For XHTML form elements, for instance, you may want to specify attributes such as the class or id. To facilitate this are a set of accessors:
>
> setAttrib($name, $value): add an attribute
>
> setAttribs(array $attribs): like addAttribs(), but overwrites
>
> getAttrib($name): retrieve a single attribute value
>
> getAttribs(): retrieve all attributes as key/value pairs
>
> Most of the time, however, you can simply access them as object properties, as Zend_Form_Element utilizes overloading to facilitate access to them:
>
> ```
> // Equivalent to $element->setAttrib('class', 'text'):
> $element->class = 'text;
> <="" span="">
> ```
>
> By default, all attributes are passed to the view helper used by the element during rendering, and rendered as HTML attributes of the element tag.

so you could also do `$element->title = 'My title text'`